# Windowing functions perform poorly after upgrade from SQL Server 2012 to SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, window-functions, sql-server-2016, database-performance

I am currently involved in the upgrade of a server from Microsoft SQL Server 2012 to 2016. Following the upgrade, we are finding that objects with windowing functions are behaving very poorly.

By "windowing functions," I mean statements like `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ... ORDER BY ...)` or `LAG(...) OVER (PARTITION BY ... ORDER BY ...)`.

We can fix the performance issues by replacing these functions with MIN/MAX and extra joins.

For example, something like this behaves poorly:

```
FROM 
    table1 AS t1
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT
         t2.ID,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t2.ID ORDER BY t2.ROW_ID DESC) AS RowNum
     FROM 
         table2 AS t2
     WHERE 
         t2.flag = -1) AS t2Rollup ON t2Rollup.RowNum = 1 
                                   AND t2Rollup.ID = t1.ID
WHERE 
    t1.ID LIKE '%042'
```

Changing it to this dramatically improves performance:

```
FROM 
    table1 AS t1
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT
         t2.ID,
         MAX(t2.ROW_ID) AS MaxRowID
     FROM 
         table2 AS t2
     WHERE 
         t2.flag = -1
     GROUP BY 
         t2.ID) AS MaxRow ON MaxRow.ID = t1.ID
LEFT JOIN 
    table2 AS t2Rollup ON t2Rollup.ID = MaxRow.ID
                       AND t2Rollup.ROW_ID = MaxRow.MaxRowID
WHERE 
    t1.ID LIKE '%042'
```

In these examples, table1 has 1 row per ID, and table2 has multiple rows per ID but unique `ROW_ID`s. I include the `WHERE` to insinuate that there are many more IDs in the tables than ultimately need to be considered for the output.

Inspecting the execution plan suggests that in the first case, SQL Server is sorting many more rows than actually need to be considered for the final query. I.e., it is sorting rows where t1.ID does not end in '042'. Even if I'm wrong about that, it is definitely spending a lot of time sorting.

One final clue, I think (but am not 100% sure) that we did not have this problem immediately following the upgrade. However, we were having other problems, notably with queries involving table variables, so we tried first turning Legacy Cardinality Estimation on, then turning that off and changing the compatibility level to SQL Server 2012 (110). After changing that setting, this problem appeared across many procedures.

**My question is this**: is anyone aware of database-wide configuration issue or settings that could explain this problem? I do not think it's an issue with the specific procedures, as they worked fine on our SQL Server 2012 instances. I do think there's a more than decent chance of something being wrong with configuration settings on the server or databases.

I have so far simply been replacing window functions with schemes based on MIN/MAX and multiple subqueries. I have inspected database configuration settings but was not able to come up with ideas.

Comment: Does the execution plan change if you have (select from t1... where t1.ID LIKE '%042') before the join?

Comment: I can only provide troubleshooting suggestions. But (ideally) when you upgrade SQL Server (often onto a new server as well), I find it best to start on with the compatibility level set to the old version (e.g., 2012) for a few weeks. If you're finding problems, then it is likely a setup (and/or hardware) issue on the new server. If you can find a query that runs poorly, then run the same thing on the new and old servers; compare the execution plans and statistics. If they're the same plan but one takes longer, then why? Similarly, if they're different plans, then why?.

Comment: Why would you be putting the work in to upgrade to a version that itself went out of mainstream support 1.5 years ago?

Comment: JJ32 - It helps if the ROW_NUMBER function is isolated and the ID limitation is within the same SELECT statement. The issue seems to be that SQL can't recognize limitations from the larger query.

// seanb - I no longer have access to the old server. Others do, but I'm having trouble getting help from them. That's good advice, though.

// Stu - Yeah, it's a stupid decision on its face. There are some circumstances that explain the decision, but I probably shouldn't post about those.

Comment: In lieu of managerial-level decisions, could you check if you have t2.ROW_ID in a composite index sorted descending? Ideally you'd have better resources to work with, we've all been there.

Comment: JJ32 - Definitely might help. I've been watching out for indexing opportunities but not for the sort of the index. Every little bit helps, so thanks for the suggestion.